# case statement syntax error in sqlite db

Tags: sqlite

I have to check if a record exists in DB then `update it`, otherwise insert a new record. but it is giving error. how should I improve that query ?

```
  CASE
    WHEN exists(select * from BackedUpDataIndex where filePath = 'C:\ttt') THEN
(update BackedUpDataIndex set flags =14 where
    (exists(select * from BackedUpDataIndex where filePath = 'C:\ttt')))
    ELSE insert into BackedUpDataIndex (filePath) values ('Hiii')
  END
```

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a `CASE` expression to conditionally execute a DML statement.  But you may try the following rewrite of your logic which should work:

```
UPDATE BackedUpDataIndex
SET flags = 14
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM BackedUpDataIndex WHERE filePath = 'C:\ttt');

INSERT INTO BackedUpDataIndex (filePath)
SELECT 'Hiii'
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM BackedUpDataIndex WHERE filePath = 'C:\ttt') AND
    (SELECT Changes() = 0);
```

The above logic is that if the `EXISTS` clause be true, then the update would happen, and the insert would not happen, and vice-versa if exists be false.

Comment: do we need to use changes()=0 here? If we not use changes()=0 then also it will work, right? because I am executing this case from c++ code and there multiple times I will be calling this case to update db or insert record.

Comment: @aromahola Right on, in that case you might not need it.

Comment: yeah, I tried above statements, 1st statement works but second is not working

Comment: Sorry...an `INSERT` statement does not take a `WHERE` clause.  But we can rewrite it using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`.

Comment: yes, but again we are using 2 queries for 1 operation. I need to optimize it so I was asking how can we use conditional statement here. we should check only once if record is present and update it else insert it. Can you please telll me if  we can do this?

Comment: SQLite doesn't really support dynamic SQL, and I don't know of a way to do this atomically.